# Migration from Single Farm Instance to Mini Role Instance

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, migration

Is it possible to convert a running single farm instance *(SharePoint 2016)* into a mini role instance and then add new server to this farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it. Here is [MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/role-conversion-using-minrole-in-sharepoint-server-2016) about it.

**How to change a server role**:

**To change a server role by using the Central Administration Web site**

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a
   member of the local **Administrators group**.
2. On the Central Administration web site, click **System Settings**.
3. On the System Settings page, click **Convert server role in this farm.**
4. On the Role Conversion page, in the **New Role** area, click the
   drop-down box to select the new server role for each server to
   change.
5. Click **Apply**.

**To change a server role by using PowerShell**
 1. Verify that you have the following memberships:
 - **securityadmin** fixed server role on the SQL Server instance.
 - **db_owner** fixed database role on all databases that are to be updated.
  2. In Start find **SharePoint Management Shell**.
  3. Run command `Set-SPServer -Identity <server name> -Role <server role>`

*Hope it helps!*